# XFCE Genmon Help

Tags: xfce

I've install https://goodies.xfce.org/projects/panel-plugins/xfce4-genmon-plugin#usage

But how to I add scripts and start them?

Answer (score 2):

(On panel right click → 'Add New Item' → 'Generic Monitor')
Then you simply link to the desired script via the 'command' within the GenMon item properties.
FYI **genmon** is short for **Generic Monitor**. follow usage:
https://goodies.xfce.org/projects/panel-plugins/xfce4-genmon-plugin#usage